# Consequences if Cramer's conjecture fails

Tags: number-theory

Questions here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/198933/zeta-functions-versus-cramers-conjecture, here [Cramer and Riemann Conjecture Implication](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087381/cramer-and-riemann-conjecture-implication) query on relation of Cramer and Riemann zeta functions.

Is there an important consequence that could happen if Cramer's conjecture fails?

Answer (score 1):

I think I will skip the part about being important. There is a formulation by Nicolas of a simple condition that is equivalent to RH and involves primorials, so it is easier to compute with than Robin's Criterion; Robin was his student.

There is a real number calculated in the criterion of Nicolas that is, as far as anyone has computed, strictly increasing as we got through the primorial numbers. Later, however, Planat et al showed that strict increasing forever would disprove Cramer's conjecture.  Meanwhile item 84 in [NICOLAS](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html)

[PLANAT](http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613)

Let's see, taking consecutive primorials $P,$ the function that, so far, keeps growing is
$$ \frac{e^\gamma \; \log \log P \; \; \phi(P)}{P}.  $$
The really nice part is that we don't need to calculate $P$ itself. For each new prime factor $p,$ add $\log p$ to update $\log P,$ and multiply by 
$$ \left( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \right) $$ to update 
$$ \frac{\phi(P)}{P}. $$ By the time $p=211$ we have Nicolas' ratio reaching $0.97.$

Comment: very interesting.

Comment: "A natural approach to derive
this inequality would be to prove that a specific sequence related to that bound is strictly
decreasing. We show that, unfortunately, this latter fact would contradict Cram´er conjecture
on gaps between consecutive primes." Seems to imply RH iumplies no Cramer's conjecture.

Comment: @Turbo, not at all. It says that if the sequence of reals (which has lim sup equal to $1$) increases forever, then it is always below $1$ and RH is true, but Cramer is false. If the sequence eventually oscillates, then we have said nothing about Cramer or about RH. In human terms, all this says is that no-one is ever going to prove either possiblity for the sequence of reals.

Comment: "In human terms, all this says is that no-one is ever going to prove either possiblity for the sequence of reals" seems very pessimistic of human capability. Afterall it just took 2000 years to construct some polygons using straight edge/compass, nowdays even polyhedra building is routine on a 3D machine.

Comment: Could you please comment on how you obtained update formula?

Comment: @WillJagy So are you biased towards Cramer's conjecture to be false?

Comment: @WillJagy It seems that this has complexity theory implication http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4769/an-np-complete-variant-of-factoring.

Comment: @Turbo, my guess is that the sequence eventually oscillates, so there is no resulting comment on either Cramer or RH.

Comment: http://vixra.org/pdf/1512.0006v1.pdf opinion?